# How do i randomly pick 5 from 10 players and each of them all have different randomly picked y coordinate from a list?

Tags: python, list, random, pygame, sprite

So i'm trying to build a "horse race" game and i want to randomly pick out 5 players from a list of 10 players and 5 of them all have different randomly picked y coordinates from a list. I tried my code but the y's sometimes are the same. I'm kinda stuck and i really appreciate if you guys can help me.

```
class Player1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):      #Player1 class ( 2-10 are the same)
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/1.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/2.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/3.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/4.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/5.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/6.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/7.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/8.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/9.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("image/pig/non/10.png").convert_alpha(), (80, 60)))
    
        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x, pos_y))

    def update(self):
        self.current_sprite += 0.1
        if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
            self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]

player_x = 100

random_y = [sf_height-200, sf_height - 290,sf_height-345,sf_height - 420,sf_height - 470]  

player1 = Player1(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player2 = Player2(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player3 = Player3(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player4 = Player4(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player5 = Player5(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player6 = Player6(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player7 = Player7(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player8 = Player8(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player9 = Player9(player_x,random.choice(random_y))
player10 = Player10(player_x,random.choice(random_y))

player_list = [player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10]

player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(random.sample(player_list, 5))
```

Comment: `positions = random.shuffle(random_y)` to create a copy of the list randomly shuffled. `Player1(player_x,positions.pop())` grab and remove the first random element for each player

Comment: @TheLazyScripter The problem is that `random_y` has only 5, not 10 entries. I think we need to see more of `Player1-10` (shouldn't the index be a parameter?) before coming to a solution.

Comment: Ah you are correct, I guess I didn't notice there were only 5 y pos's. Would make sense to assign the y_pos after selecting the random player. Is player1-10 an object or a fn?

Comment: player1-10 is an object @TheLazyScripter

Comment: I would say set the ypos after initialization then. `players = random.sample(player_list, 5)`, then set the ypos after shuffle. `random.shuffle(random_y)`. `for x in players:x.set_y(random_y.pop())`. `set_y` method would then create the `rect`. A copy could be made of `random_y` to retain the origional positions by `random_y_copy = random_y.copy()` and then shuffle and pop from the copy instead of the origional! Hope this helps!

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each of the 5 `y` coordinates to 5 `Player1` class objects. It won't be random at first, but it will automatically be shuffled when you use `random.sample` on the list:

```
player_x = 100
random_y = [sf_height - 200, sf_height - 290, sf_height - 345, sf_height - 420, sf_height - 470]  

five_players = [Player1(player_x,random.choice(y)) for y in random_y]
all_players = [...]
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(random.sample(five_players, 5))
```